# Wordpress web pages keep getting deleted (moved into the trash) by themselves

Tags: plugins, pages

I'm new to Wordpress. My Wordpress web pages keep getting deleted (moved into the trash) by themselves, without any input from me. Luckily I have made a backup with `All in one migration` tool, prior to the issue. But this is my third upload of the backup, and after just a few minutes the pages all get moved into the trash, and my website would load up a sample page instead. The same thing happens again and again, after every backup restoration.
[image]

I can't quite narrow down the issue. Here's a list of all the plugins I have installed:
[image]
[image]

I tried to update all my plugins, but it didn't matter, the files get automatically moved to trash, after just a few minutes. It's as if a software/plugin/schedule or something else is set to move them all to the trash. The only other thing I'm doing after restoring the backup is changing my administrator password. I can't imagine that would do anything.

The other thing I'm suspecting is one of the security packages - Wordfence or iTheme Security. But I can't tell. I've looked at their dashboards, no indication that they moved web pages into the trash.

Comment: First, Weclome to Wordpress Development! Second, Disable all your plugins, and all your themes, then try making a new page and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and response Nathaniel. Well I can restore the 7 pages that are in the trash. After that they don't get moved back into the trash, they stay published. But the damage is already done, because originaly there were 12 pages, and now I'm left with 7 in the trash and the others gone permanently. Would it be better if I restore, and then immediately after I restore, I disable all plugins?

Comment: I would backup eveything, then restore then re-enabled your plugins one at a time, **_MAKE A BACKUP FIRST!!!!!!!!!!_**

Comment: By the time I export a backup file, which takes time, the pages get deleted by then, half way through my backup.

Comment: I meant open the file copy the insides then past it in like a google doc, sorry that was my bad, I should have been more clear, I am sorry. I think you can get them back, look in your MYSQL database, phpMyAdmin is a good tool to access the Mysql database.

Comment: No problem Nathaniel. I'll try this tomorrow, or the day after and see. This is a side project for me, and I have other deadlines. I haven't played around much with phpMyAdmin.  I thought it was something more obvious that others have experienced, and quick to fix. No problem. I'll look into your suggestion and will update if I find the issue. Thanks